# Custom Table Cell Values Changing For Other Cells when Selected

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i am using Custom cell in my code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell is called %d",indexPath.row);
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"partner";

    FindPartnerCell *cell = (FindPartnerCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"FindPartner" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    FindPartnersList *list=[self.serachPartners objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.namesOfPartner.text=list.email;
    cell.companys.text=list.phone;

    UIButton *currentButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
    currentButton.tag=indexPath.row;

    [currentButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressing:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    currentButton.frame = CGRectMake(22, 10, 27, 23);

    [currentButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    currentButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [cell.cellsView addSubview:currentButton];


    return cell;



}
```

When i tryed to changed the custom cell image. i selected the image it will call to  in

```
-(void) buttonPressing : (id) sender
{
    UIButton *clicked = (UIButton *) sender;
    [clicked setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab1.png"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

When I selected a particular cell means, it will change the image to all the other cell. It will changes a 4+ increment.

When I click four means it will made changes in `4,8,16`.

So have to say how to change the custom cell values.

Comment: What is currently happening when you tap one of the buttons? Are you having a specific problem, or are you just unsure on how to make the changes in rows based on very simple math?

Comment: Use Tag for each image and according to tag Handle your data.